My custom error message doesn't show up when a banned word goes through
The "this is a family friendly website" doesn't show up I've tried fixing it but it either breaks the site or repeats the phrase more than necessary. I just want the phrase to show up once when a banned comment is entered
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Insert Page page</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
    <?php
        // Establish database connection
        $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "reviewsite");

        // Error message for family-friendly website
        $error = "This is a family friendly website.";

        // Check database connection
        if ($conn === false) {
            die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }

        // Extract review data from form input
        $review = $_REQUEST['Rev'];
        $originals = array("fuck", "damn", "ass", "shit", "instance8");

        $boolean = true;
        for ($x = 0; $x < count($originals); $x++) {
            $bad = $originals[$x];
            if (strstr($review, $bad)) {
                $boolean = false;
                $error = $error;
            }
        }

        // Perform insert query execution
        $sql = "INSERT INTO revtable VALUES ('$review')";
        
        if ($boolean) {
            if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
                echo "<h3> Thank you for your review! </h3>";
                // echo nl2br("\n $review");//
            }
        }
    ?>
    <table/>
</center>
</body>
</html>


Aside: Learn to use foreach to loop over an array. foreach ($originals as $bad)

You should break out of the loop once you find a match.

What's the point of $error = $error;?

You have nothing that displays $error when $boolean is false.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your script is vulnerable to SQL Injection Attack. Even if you are escaping variables, its not safe! You should always use prepared statements and parameterized queries in either MYSQLI or PDO instead of concatenating variables into the query.

You need to display the error message.
After displaying the error message, break out of the loop so you only show it once.

        $boolean = true;
        for ($x = 0; $x < count($originals); $x++) {
            $bad = $originals[$x];
            if (strstr($review, $bad)) {
                $boolean = false;
                echo "<h3> $error </h3>";
                break;
            }
        }

